# Solve differential equation. Not able to apply any standard formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(D^2-6D+13)y=3^x.$ How to approach this problem? All of the formulas i have learnt till now do not fit in this problem

Comment: What have you learnt so far? Does this look similar to problems you've seen before? Have you seen $D$ previously, and what does it mean?

Comment: ofcourse i know that stuff. I am confused about the rhs part. All the questions i have solved till now didn't have a similar rhs

Comment: Hint: $3^x=e^{\ln(3) x}.$

Comment: It would be useful to clarify exactly what's confusing you in the original post, so you can receive the best responses.

Comment: is $D=\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: I suppose $D$ is $\frac{d}{dx},$ so that $D^2 y=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$y'' - 6y' + 13y = 3^x$$

First of all solve the homogeneous equation

$$y'' - 6y' + 13y = 0$$

Whose characteristic equation is

$$z^2 - 6z + 13 = 0$$

$$\mathbf{z} = \frac{6\pm\sqrt{36 - 52}}{2} = \frac{6\pm 2i}{2}$$

$$z_0 = 3+2i$$

$$z_1 = 3-2i$$

By the theoryuld know how to arrange them to create the homogeneous solution $Y_o$.

After this you need the particular solution.

Write $3^X$ as $e^{x\ln(3)}$ and then use the function $Y_p = A e^{Bx}$, differentiate and solve for $A$ and $B$ et voilà.

$$Y = Y_o + Y_p$$